# Factory method with abstract classes

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory, factory-method

Good morning everyone! 
I have a problem with an implementation of a videogame and I would ask here for some help.
I have two types of action in my project, "mainaction" and "quickaction", both of them have some subclasses that would implement a specific method, "execute" for example.
I would like to use the factory method to implement this situation, so I instantiate an interface called "Action" and the two classes of action would implement that interface.

my question is about how to use the factory in this case, with mainaction and quickaction or it would be better to implement a factory with the subclasses of them? how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If your clients only need methods declared in IAction, then have the Factory return IAction.  For example,

```
public static IAction Create(string details) {...}
```

If your clients need methods specific to QuickAction and MainAction, then have 2 methods in your Factory.  For example,

```
public static MainAction CreateMainAction(string details) {...}
public static QuickAction CreateQuickAction(string details) {...}
```

The implementation of these methods use `details` to create the specific subclasses.  The clients should never need to cast; rather, they rely on polymorphism.